# Rails 3 hosting iFrames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing an application for my company in which i need to show one part of my site on another site through an iFrame. While developing I'm requesting the iFrame through:

```
http://localhost:3000/frame
```

Which in turn is routed to the **FrameController** that includes the method index.

Now the problem is that when i refresh page holding the iFrame it renders:

---

## **Routing Error**

```
No route matches "/frame"
```

---

So I know for sure it is connecting with my rails application, but for some reason the routes break in the process. Note that just requesting the rails application's root http://localhost:3000/ works without any problems at all.

If I try to visit the same page directly in my browser on the other hand it renders properly.

It would be of great help if anybody could assist me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question but have you included the following in your routes.rb file?

```
match '/frame', :to => 'frame#index'
```

also run rake routes to ensure that the route you are using is properly represented

Comment: I just tried that and came back to say i found a solution.
Thank you anyway, greatly appreciated.